# Razor code between double quotes

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, razor, templating

In a Razor View Engine template, I want to do the following: I want to put some *code* between the double quotes of an html *attribute*.  The trouble is that the piece of code I want to insert contains some double quotes itself.

```
<a href="Url.Action("Item", new { id = Model.Item.Id, page = page });">@page</a>
```

You can easily see how things turn horribly wrong :-)  I know i can calculate the link in a variable and then use it, but I'd rather not:

```
@{ var action = Url.Action("Question", new { id = Model.Question.Id, page = page }); }                   
<a href="@action">@page</a>
```

Answer (score 21, accepted):

You don't need to escape or anything using Razor. Razor is smart enough to know when quotes are within attributes because you're escaping outside of html when you parse it.

```
<a href="@Url.Action("Item", 
       new { id = Model.Item.Id, page = page })">@page</a>
```

That code will work fine - Just make sure you have the `@` symbol in front of the `Url.Action` call because if you don't it won't be parsed properly and I notice you don't have it in your question.

Edit: removed ; as Url.Action is not a statement.

Comment: One note: if you need a constant prefix in your attribute combined with Razor expression, you need to add parenthesis after the @ char, otherwise Razor treats it as an e-mail address. Example: `id="prefix@(Model.Id)"`

Answer (score 8):

Maybe I didn't understand your question in which case please correct me but can't you simply:

```
@Html.ActionLink(page, "Question", new { id = Model.Question.Id, page = page })
```

Answer (score 3):

This may be correct :

```
href="@(action)"> @page
```

Comment: Sad you got down voted - the solution to my problem was to add @(xxx) instead of without the ()'s - and I presume that is what you were saying - put the 'action' stuff inside ()'s  - which solved my problem exactly,  @xxx didn't work inside of ""