# Render Razor in Html.Raw() (MVC3)

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-3, razor

Is it possible to render Razor in Html.Raw()? I have a dynamic page being generated that uses the Html.Raw() method to render the page that is created in the controller. Inside this page I have an image tag that should retrieve the image via Url.Action.

```
var image = string.Format("<img src=\"@Url.Action(\"GetImage\", \"ImageUtility\")?id={0}\" alt=\"{1}\" />", Image.ImageId, Image.Name);
```

As you can see this would render the following without the razor being rendered:

```
<img src="@Url.Action("GetImage", "ImageUtility")?id=10000" alt="Image Name" />
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try wrapping `Url.Action` with parenthesis.

See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4249994/290343) and @Igor's comment related to.

Comment: It was my fault, I thought it was a razor problem but I quickly figured out that my routing had messed up the call to the action. Although I have hit a road block getting CSS to render?

Comment: I didn't understand what you mean in your last sentence... could you explain?

Comment: It's ok I fixed it. My issue was getting pulling css from a database and rendering it in a view.